# Pass data from actions in reducer

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

How to pass data to reducer?

I have action like this

```
export function loginFailed(error){
return {
    type: types.LOG_IN_ERROR,
    error
  }
}
```

And i want pass error in my reducer and after show error in my view component

```
export function loginUser(credentials) {
return function(dispatch) {
    return sessionApi.login(credentials).then(response => {

            dispatch(loginFailed(response.status));

    }).catch(error => {
        throw(error);
    });
  };
}
```

For example i trying to pass `response status`.

Here is my reducer

```
export const errorMessage = (state = null, action) => {
switch(action.type){
    case LOG_IN_ERROR:
        return action.errorMessage
    default:
        return state;
   }
}
```

And my view 
When i'm trying to pass this error

```
function mapStateToProps(state, ownProps) {
return {
    errorMessage: state.error
};
}
```

And just `this.props.errorMessage`. And i getting undefined :/

Hope your help

Comment: `return action.errorMessage` you're not supposed to return that. You're supposed to ALWAYS return a new state. e.g. `return {...state, error: action.errorMessage}`

Comment: Only way to pass data to reducer by using the action payload inside action creator.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are pretty close, only a little off. You are passing the `error` object in your action creator.

```
return { type: types.LOG_IN_ERROR, error }
```

So in your reducer, you can access that object via `action.error`, not `action.errorMessage`.

As another user mentioned, return a new object:

```
return {...state, error: action.error}
```

And in your mapStateToProps, you can access the error prop like so :

```
function mapStateToProps(state) {
  return {
    errorMessage: state.error
  };
}
```